# EDI Inquiry: Is this an acceptable way to retrieve EDI encoded data?

Tags: parsing, edi

I'm new to EDI, and I have a question.

I have read that you can get most of what you need about an EDI format by looking at the last 3 characters of the ISA line.  This is fine if every EDI used line breaks to separate entities, but I have found that many are single line files with any number of characters used as breaks.  I have noticed that the VERY last character in every EDI I've parsed is the break character.  I've looked at a few hundred, and have found no exceptions to this.  If I first grab that character, and use that to obtain the last 3 of the ISA line, should I reasonably expect that I will be able to parse data from an EDI?

I don't know if this helps, but the EDI 'types' in question tend to be 850, 875.  I'm not sure if that is a standard or not, but it may be worth mentioning.

Comment: Testing.. question hasn't showed up on the index after 4 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be the same as this:
[Reading EDI Formatted Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117897/reading-edi-formatted-files)